# ECC Encryption with BouncyCastle for C#

Tags: c#, winforms, licensing, cryptography, bouncycastle

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646086/implementation-for-product-keys/646536#646536) regarding the use ECC to implement the hashing using aa private key I set about trying to find an implementation of ECDH and [came across BoucyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690566/net-implementation-libraries-of-elliptic-curve-cryptography/744839#744839).

Unfortunately documentation is minimal (as in zerow!) and I'm unsure what [I'm about to accomplish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896336/securing-c-application-suggestions) is completely correct/valid.

We want to simply hash 4 strings which will be the users registration information (Name, Company, their company ID and their account ID which are both 12 characters long) which will then compute a serial they can  use to activate our software.

I have generated a key pair using PUTTYGEN.exe but I cannot workout how to apply this with BouncyCastle, which class can I use to get started? Are there any examples out there?

So far I've concatenated the information and computed a MD5 hash of it (using the .NET classes) I cannot use the new VISTA enhanced API functions as we target XP still - .NET 3.5.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As an aside, what's to stop someone from replacing the public key used to verify the license information? I wouldn't go too far out of your way on this, since breaking the scheme wouldn't be difficult. If you're more familiar with another library or authentication scheme, use that instead.

Comment: Actually I thought of the same thing but I figured it couldn't be that easy to fool. I guess not! What does everyone think of the Xml Digital Signature that jspcal mentioned?

Comment: Of course it's that easy to fool. That's why there is no viable DRM scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think .NET has the RSACryptoServiceProvider class which is a full RSA implementation.

There's sample code for your particular application here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/xmldsiglic.aspx

In this example they use MS's sn.exe tool to create the key.

Comment: This seems like the way to go! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

*So far I've concatenated the information and computed a MD5 hash of it (using the .NET classes).....*
That statement in itself worries me. MD5 is seriously crackable - not just theoretically but practically. Please, please don't use MD5 for secure hashing.  Use SHA-256 or SHA-512  and here's [why](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=386193)

Also the post you linked is not quite true - yes symmetric algorithms use the same key to encrypt/decrypt but public/private key is not a magic bullet.

1) Public/private key is slow
2) Most publicc/private algorithms just encrypt the symmetric key and then use symmetric encryption for the data because it's much faster

The point is that a good hashing algorithm is non-reversible and hence very difficult to crack so is perfectly fine for your purposes.  However, I'd suggest using a SALT, which is a cryptographically random number to add to your user data then hash that data as it makes your data much safer against dictionary attacks ( where hackers use well know terms and variants to crack passwords )